# Project Euler #12: Highly divisible triangular number

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I want to receive advice on my code. It is too slow... The problem I am trying to solve is:

> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import copy
from operator import add
memoi_table = {}

#check whether the x is prime or not
#to do a prime factorization
def prime_finder(x):
    cnt = 0
    a = math.sqrt(x)
    sqrt_number = int(math.floor(a))
    for i in range(2,sqrt_number+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            cnt = cnt +1
            break
    if cnt == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Do a prime_factorization
#Do a dynamic programing with memoization table
#Do a recursive method to cover the triangular number
#ex)Triangular number = 1,3,6,10,15,21,28
#When we treat 10, we couldn't utilize dynamic programming => Recursive method
def prime_factorization(x):
    global memoi_table
    memoi_table[x] = {}

    if prime_finder(x) == True:
        memoi_table[x][x] = 1

    for i in range(2,math.floor(math.sqrt(x)+1)):
        if (prime_finder(i) == True) and (x % i == 0):
            new_x = x / i
            if not new_x in memoi_table.keys():
                prime_factorization(new_x)
                #Recursive way

            if new_x in memoi_table.keys():
                memoi_table[x] = memoi_table[new_x].copy()
                #to shallow copy
            if i in memoi_table[x].keys():
                memoi_table[x][i] = memoi_table[x][i] + 1
            else:
                memoi_table[x][i] = 1
    return (x,memoi_table[x])
#ex) 20 => return (20,(2:2,5:1))


# To calculate the number of divisor based on prime factorization
def find_number_of_divisor(x):
    global memoi_table
    number_of_divisor = 1
    for key in memoi_table[x].keys():
        number_of_divisor = number_of_divisor * (memoi_table[x][key]+1)
    return number_of_divisor

#Let's do it
def main():
    global memoi_table
    n = 0
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        Triangular_number = n * (n + 1) / 2
        prime_factorization(Triangular_number)
        num_divisor = find_number_of_divisor(Triangular_number)

        if num_divisor > 500:
            return (Triangular_number,num_divisor)
            break

print(main())
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=euler+12+python

Answer (score 2):

**The Algorithm**

Let's just look at your top level algorithm:

```
n = 0
while True:
    n = n + 1
    Triangular_number = n * (n + 1) / 2
    prime_factorization(Triangular_number)
    num_divisor = find_number_of_divisor(Triangular_number)
```

Factoring is *hard*. It's a difficult problem in the best of cases. You are taking a difficult problem and making it *harder*. You are starting with `n * (n + 1) / 2` - that is already a partial factorization. You are then throwing out that information and factoring the whole number. It is much easier to factor `7 * 4` than it is to factor `28`, but you are choosing to do the latter.

It would be much more efficient to do something like:

```
factor1 = prime_factorization(n/2 if n % 2 == 0 else n)
factor2 = prime_factorization(n+1 if n % 2 == 0 else (n+1)/2)
full_factorization = merge(factor1, factor2)
```

If you memoize `prime_factorization`, then you're only doing a little bit of work each iteration. Let's consider just going from the 49th triangular number to the 50th and assume we have a very good memoized prime factorization (more on this later). Factoring the full number:

```
(1275)
--> 3 * (425)
--> 3 * 5 * (85)
--> 3 * 5 * 5 * (17)
```

None of 1275, 425, or 85 were in the table. 17 was the first number we would have found. Consider the alternative, we are instead finding the prime factorization of:

```
(25)
--> memoized as 5*5 (already done when finding the 24th triangular number) 
(51)
--> 3 * (17)
```

And `17` is memoized already (from the 16th triangular number). So we did **one** division. That time difference adds up. The full solution I present later in this answer takes just under 1.0s (when run 10x) if I factor each factor independently, but 4.46s when I factor the whole number. That is **a lot** slower.

And when you find yourself doing a counting loop, you should really use `itertools.count()` so that the main loop becomes:

```
for n in itertools.count(start=1):
    factors1 = prime_factorization(n/2 if n % 2 == 0 else n)
    factors2 = prime_factorization(n+1 if n % 2 == 0 else (n+1)/2)
    full_factorization = merge_factors(factors1, factors2)

    if num_factors(full_factorization) >= 500:
        return n * (n+1) / 2
```

**Memoization**

Now, you're kind of memoizing, but then not really, since the first thing you do is wipe `memoi_table[x]`. If should definitely start with:

```
def prime_factorization(x):
    if x in memoi_table:
        return memoi_table[x]

    ...
```

In any event, it's simpler to just write a decorator:

```
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if not args in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrapper

@memoize
def prime_factorization(x):
    ...
```

**Prime Finder**

If you do your loop correctly, you don't actually need `prime_finder(i)`. What does that function do? It looks over all the numbers smaller than `i`... but we're already doing that in `prime_factorization`! You're just doubling work for no reason. The whole body should just be something like:

```
for i in range(2,math.floor(math.sqrt(x)+1)):
    if x%i == 0:
        old_factorization = prime_factorization(x / i).copy()
        old_factorization[i] += 1
        return old_factorization

# still here? we didn't find a factor, must be prime
res = collections.defaultdict(int)
res[x] = 1
return res
```

That's it.

**Putting it all together**

All we need is merging two dictionaries, which is an easy loop:

```
def merge_factors(f1, f2):
    res = f1.copy()
    for k, v in f2.items():
        res[k] += v
    return res
```

And finding the number of factors, which is just a product:

```
def num_factors(factorization):
    product = 1 
    for v in factorization.values():
        product *= (v+1)
    return product
```

The times based on finding the first triangular number with at least X factors:

```
      mine      OP
  5   0.0005s   0.0007s
 10   0.0009s   0.0041s
 25   0.0039s   0.0860s
100   0.0256s   6.0304s
500   0.9849s   ???????
```